# civiVolunteer database table creation?

Tags: database, civivolunteer

When are civiVolunteer database tables created? When I run a search on volunteer opportunities and when a donation is made to our organization, we get database errors saying that tables civicrm_value_civivolunteer_5 and civicrm_value_civivolunteer_7 are missing. An inspection of the database reveals that we have a table called civicrm_value_civivolunteer_3, but that's it.

I cannot disable civiVolunteer without an error, which is another clue that something is wrong with the civiVolunteer installation.  I recently took over this website, so I do not know any of the specifics of the installation. I just need to fix the problems.

So, does anyone know what I need to do to get the missing tables in place? Will reinstalling civiVolunteer be enough?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the data in the volunteer tables?

Comment: It seems we only have 1 table in the current database and very little info in it. It can be added again. It's more important to fix this problem because it is affecting membership joins and renewals, as well as donations.

Answer (score 1):

Those tables are for custom data. CiviVolunteer uses standard CiviCRM custom data tables (created in the normal way, just as you would create custom fields) so that error is rather unusual. Was the site migrated from one server to another?

Comment: Yes, just before this started, the previous web admin migrated the website.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this? Can I just uninstall civiVolunteer and then reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can resolve this by deleting the records in `civicrm_custom_group` which name the missing tables in the `table_name` column. (As always, make a backup and try it on a sandbox first, if you can.)

My guess as to the site got this way? Running the CiviVolunteer installer multiple times.